# What should be included in a git repo?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I'm new to programming and working with git and github. I want to make sure my repo only has the necessary files in it, and since I work in virtual environments, each environment has folders that were created when the environment was activated (`__pycache__`, `.vscode`, `Include`, `Lib`, `Scripts`, `tcl` etc). Am I correct to assume that these are of no use to anyone in the repo and can be added to the `.gitignore`?

Comment: See https://www.gitignore.io/ and https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my GitHub to hold everything that I'm working on in a given project.  In the event that I want to make some changes while I'm away from my desk but don't have the most up to date code on whichever workstation I happen to be working on, I just pull the repo down, make my changes, and push them back to the repo.  What you should consider when you're trying to organize your repo is containment.  If I pull this repo down, will I be able to work and test the code completely as if I was working on the original source files.  Even if a file isn't being changed very often, if it is an essential piece of the project, you should include it, or at the very least have an alternative method of obtaining it, like Christopher was suggesting.  Your working environment itself should not be included because others who may download your repo may not work in the same environment that you do but should still be able write and modify the code as needed within their own environment.

TLDR: Your repo should contain everything required to modify and test the code as if you were working on it from your original project directory.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you keep the record of the installed files somewhere e.g. py-req or something that other user can replicate on his/her virtualenv you can skip them in your repo

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of the repo is to track files that you are working on - so if they aren't files that you edit, there is probably no reason to track them.